# Expand data.frame using vector of values present in one column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(entrez = c(1:10, 1), entrez_HS = c(11:19, 19, 20))

   entrez entrez_HS
1       1        11
2       2        12
3       3        13
4       4        14
5       5        15
6       6        16
7       7        17
8       8        18
9       9        19
10     10        19
11      1        20
```

I also have vector of values that exist in `df$entrez_HS`:

```
entrez_HS <- c(11, 11, 12, 19, 19)
```

For every value in `entrez_HS`, I want the row(s) of `df` where `df$entrez_HS` is equal to the value.  Duplicate entries in `entrez_HS` should result in duplicated rows. Here is the result that I would expect for the above `df`:

```
   entrez entrez_HS
1      1        11
2      1        11
3      2        12
4      9        19
5     10        19
6      9        19
7     10        19
```

Not sure how to approach this? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`merge` the data together:

```
merge(mget("entrez_HS"), df, by="entrez_HS")
#or
merge(data.frame(entrez_HS), df, by="entrez_HS")

#  entrez_HS entrez
#1        11      1
#2        11      1
#3        12      2
#4        19      9
#5        19     10
#6        19      9
#7        19     10
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using any package, we can try this:

```
# Create data
df <- data.frame(entrez = c(1:10, 1), entrez_HS = c(11:19, 19, 20))
entrez_HS <- c(11, 11, 12, 19, 19)

# Extract information, then collect it
result <- lapply(entrez_HS, function(i) df[df$entrez_HS==i,])
result <- do.call("rbind", result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option

```
 rbind(df[match(entrez_HS, df$entrez_HS),],
         df[duplicated(df$entrez_HS)|duplicated(df$entrez_HS, 
               fromLast=TRUE),])
#    entrez entrez_HS
#1        1        11
#1.1      1        11
#2        2        12
#9        9        19
#9.1      9        19
#91       9        19
#10      10        19
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(data_frame(entrez_HS), df)
#  entrez_HS entrez
#      <dbl>  <dbl>
#1        11      1
#2        11      1
#3        12      2
#4        19      9
#5        19     10
#6        19      9
#7        19     10
```